# How to join two tables when a matching row may not potentially be in one of the tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to merge two tables, spring_stats and summer_stats, into one table in which some of the columns are the same and thus should be summed.

Each table contains (among others) the fields hunter_id, year, fowl, deer, bears where the last three represent numeric amount each hunter has caught.

The end result should be
hunter_id, year, spring.fowl + summer.fowl, spring.deer + summer.deer, etc

HOWEVER, some of the hunters may not have participated in the summer session but participated in  the spring session (or vice versa). In this case the standard

```
SELECT hunter_id, year, spring.fowl + summer.fowl AS total_fowl, ... FROM spring, summer 
WHERE spring.hunter_id = summer.hunter_id AND spring.year = summer.year
```

would not work as hunters who were active in only the spring or summer session would not be recorded and included, whereas I need all hunters included, regardless of whether they were active in only one session or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an ancient type of table join. Instead adopt the newer (since the early 90s) join syntax. Here you want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(summer.hunter_id, spring.hunter_id) as hunter_id, 
    COALESCE(summer.year, spring.year) as year, 
    spring.fowl + summer.fowl AS total_fowl, ... 
FROM spring 
    FULL OUTER JOIN summer  
        ON spring.hunter_id = summer.hunter_id 
        AND spring.year = summer.year
```

You can read up about `FULL OUTER JOIN` [here at the postgres documentation site](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM):

> First, an inner join is performed. Then, for each row in T1 that does
> not satisfy the join condition with any row in T2, a joined row is
> added with null values in columns of T2. Also, for each row of T2 that
> does not satisfy the join condition with any row in T1, a joined row
> with null values in the columns of T1 is added.

The `COALESCE()` function will first use the `hunter_id` from the `summer` table unless it's NULL (due to the FULL OUTER JOIN) in which case it will pick the `hunter_id` from the `spring` table.

---

I think it's also worth mentioning that having tables specific to your seasons may not make sense. Instead a single table where `Season` is just an added column may be a better schema:

```
 season | year | hunter_id | animal | animal_count
 summer | 2020 | 1         | fowl   | 3
 spring | 2020 | 1         | deer   | 2
 summer | 2020 | 2         | fowl   | 4
 spring | 2021 | 3         | fowl   | 1
```

Now your query is:

```
SELECT 
    hunter_id, 
    year, 
    sum(CASE WHEN animal='fowl' THEN animal_count END) as fowl_total,
    sum(CASE WHEN animal='dear' THEN animal_count END) as deer_total
FROM this_new_table
GROUP BY hunter_id, year
```

Comment: Thank you, I agree with your suggestion of having Season as a column but do not have control over merging the tables unfortunately.

Comment: Isn't that always the way with these things? We always have to build on bad ideas.